# Adding subReport runtime DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, report, subreport

I need your help . I want to add subreport in table runtime. Code is :

```
xrTableCell14.Controls.Add(xrSubreport5);
        xrSubreport5.BringToFront();
        xrSubreport5.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

But it can't show the result. I'm using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but the actual XtraReports implementation doesn't provide the capability to implement this scenario.

See this forum post at DevExpress in which multiple people have asked for the feature, but it still hasn't been implemented!

http://community.devexpress.com//forums/p/55360/186621.aspx#186621

Comment: Thanks for your post. I want to select multiple value from database into tableCell.So i use subreport. Is this another way ?

Comment: If you can mock something up (an image) and explain your table structure and the data you want to put in it I'll do my best to help you out!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Vijay. I resolved that problem . Code :

```
 sub_Rpt_Education_RPT Education = new sub_Rpt_Education_RPT();
        Education.DataSource = _dt;
        Education.DataMember = "dtEducation";
        xrSubEducation.ReportSource = Education;
        xrTableRow12.Height = Education.RowCount * 23;
```

Comment: Oh wow.  That's pretty nice code.  Perhaps you should mail the DevExpress guys and tell them to stick it in their new help center! :)